# How so I convert this SHA256 + BASE64 from Swift to PHP?

Tags: php, swift, base64, sha

I've been given this Swift code to try and make work in PHP:

```
finalStr = Encryption.sha256(inputStr)

...

    class Encryption {
        static func sha256(_ data: Data) -> Data? {
            guard let res = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)) else { return nil }
            CC_SHA256((data as NSData).bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), res.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
            return res as Data
        }

        static func sha256(_ str: String) -> String? {
            guard
                let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
                let shaData = Encryption.sha256(data)
                else { return nil }
            let rc = shaData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            return rc
        }
    }
```

I'm doing the following in PHP, but the end result isn't matching:

```
$hashedStr = hash('sha256', $inputStr);
$finalStr = base64_encode($hashedStr);
echo $finalStr;
```

What am I missing on the PHP side?

Comment: Not sure why I was down-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set raw output to true for `hash` method in PHP. Notice the third method argument in [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

```
$hashedStr = hash('sha256', $inputStr, true);
$finalStr = base64_encode($hashedStr);
echo $finalStr;
```

This way the base64_encoded raw value from PHP should be equal to the one that you get from `base64EncodedString`

Comment: That was it, thanks! I misinterpreted what that third argument was for... but it's essentially what `str.data` was doing.